# TFS Eclipse Plugin "authorization failure"

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

I am working with Eclipse Juno on a Mac running  OS 10.7.3

I installed the TFS plugin for Eclipse yesterday and today, after a few false starts,  and I was able to connect to our tfspreview instance.  I checked in all my code and then committed it.  A team mate confirmed the code had been submitted.  I then tried checking for updates and got an authorization failure message.  I have tried re-starting Eclipse and finally my computer.  Every time Eclipse tries to connect to the TFS server it fails.

I haven't changed my password and I still able to log in the tfspreview web interface, so my account does not appear to be locked.   Has anyone ever experience anything like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of the plugin did you install?  Do you get an authentication dialog popup?  If so, are you prompted for DOMAIN\username and password or are you prompted to log in with your Live ID credentials?  Are you behind a firewall and do you use a proxy to get out of your network?

Comment: I am using version 11.0.0.201. I do get an authentication dialog pop-up box and I am prompted for my username and password.  ("Enter password for https://ourserver.tfspreview.com/DefaultCollection" is what I'm presented with)  I believe that is my domain username & password; I'm not sure what my actual Live ID is.  Finally I am not behind a firewall and I do not use a proxy service.

Comment: Well, you'll definitely need to log in with your Windows ID (Live ID).  But you should be getting a similar dialog to what you get when you visit yourserver.tfspreview.com/ with a web browser.  (It should be pretty obvious that it's a web browser in that dialog.)

Comment: Did you enable basic authentication at any point?  I'm wondering if there is a combination of going from Live ID auth to basic auth that might be causing the issues you are having.

Comment: i was confused about what, exactly, my windows live id is, and it according to the MS pages i'm reading, it's just the email/password that i use to log into the tfs website.  when i set up the TFS site with the Eclipse plugin, my only option is whether or not to use http or https.  once i set up the server, i am asked for a username and password; i entered the one i use to log into the tfs website.  you mentioned live auth vs. basic auth; is there a different type of authentication i should have available as an option while setting up the TFS site in Eclipse?

Comment: anyone? :(  my manager is threatening to make me start developing on a windows virtual machine if i can't get this figured out...

Comment: i just found the error in the Team Foundation Server console window:  The SOAP endpoint http://nttsocial.tfspreview.com/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404

Comment: @lauren did you find the solution for your problem?
How did did you fix it?